# DatePicker Bootstrap lost date range after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

my application is an ASP.NET MVC and I implemented bootstrap datepicker, like below:

```
$(window).load(function () {

        var startDate = new Date('01/01/2012');
        var FromEndDate = new Date();
        var ToEndDate = new Date();

$('#DataInicio').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            startDate: '01/01/2012',
            language: "pt-BR",
            todayHighlight: true,
            endDate: FromEndDate,
            autoclose: true
        }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
            $('#DataFim').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
        });

$('#DataFim').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            language: "pt-BR",
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate: ToEndDate,
            autoclose: true
        }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
            FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
            $('#DataInicio').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
        });
```

At the first time pageload, the daterange works perfectly, but after postpack the daterange lost the configuration, the images below is first time and after postback:

[image]

[image]

The configuration to prevent choice a date start greater than end date is lost.

How can I fixed after postback and keeping the range selected?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a postback or is it been updated by ajax as window.load won't fire if it's updated with ajax you would need to update the element when the ajax call finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed using this solution:

```
if ($('#DataInicio').val()) {
    startDate = $('#DataInicio').val();
   };

if ($('#DataFim').val()) {
    FromEndDate = $('#DataFim').val();
   };
```

After postback the date range is maintained.